# Django - how to set blank = False, required = False

Tags: python, django

I've a model like this:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    msg = models.CharField(max_length = 150)
```

and I have a form for insert the field. Actually django allows empty spaces, for examples if I inset in the field one space it works. But now I want to fix this: the field is not required, but if a user insert a spaces, the validation should fail.

I've added:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    msg = models.CharField(max_length = 150, blank = False)
```

but it doesn't work.
What's the mistake?

Comment: Blank would mean an empty string (as opposed to a null value) - a string with spaces isn't blank. If you want to prevent a field having only spaces, I think you will have to write your own custom *clean* methods.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Whitespace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_(programming_language)) is not considered to be *blank*. *blank* specifically refers to *no input* (i.e. an empty string `''`). You will need to use a model field validator that raises an exception if the value only consists of spaces. See [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/validators/) for details.

Example:

```
def validate_not_spaces(value):
    if isinstance(value, str) and value.strip() == '':
        raise ValidationError(u"You must provide more than just whitespace.")

class Message(models.Model):
    msg = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False,
                           validators=[validate_not_spaces])
```

Comment: My edit has been rejected, but you should implement an `isinstance(value, str)` check in addition to `value.strip() == ''` as your original function will break if the field value it's checking is `None` type (you can't call `.strip()` on it).

Comment: no problem - I implemented this the other day so that's the only reason I caught it. While we're at it though, any reason not to do `not value.strip()` instead of `value.strip() == ''`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create your own form and perform custom validation on the field to make sure that repeated spaces are raised as a validation error. Something like this:

```
import re

class MessageForm(form.ModelForm)
    def clean_msg(self):
        msg = self.cleaned_data['msg']
        if re.match('/[\s]+$',msg):
            raise ValidationError("Spaces not allowed")
        return msg
```