# Django CharField without empty strings

Tags: python, django

Is there any way to make a CharField (or TextField) that doesn't accept empty strings? I'm trying to use `blank=False` but it's not working...

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=124, blank=False)
```

Then after `syncdb` I run `python manage.py shell`, and I can type:

```
f = Foo()
f.save()
```

and it doesn't complain. The object has a title with a value `''`. I *don't* want this to happen, I want it to complain if `Foo()` isn't explicitly given a non-empty string. Any way to do this?

I'm using Django 1.6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.blank), `blank=False` is purely validation-related that works only on a form level.

See related threads:

- [Django model blank=False does not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17816229/django-model-blank-false-does-not-work)
- [Why are blank and null distinct options for a django model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8159310/why-are-blank-and-null-distinct-options-for-a-django-model)

Comment: @gyeh you are welcome. If it's important to check for non-empty values on a model field level, consider making a validator, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/6195014/771848.

Comment: @alcxe Yeah normally I'd do that, but I'm trying to make a django-admin command that populates the database, and I wanted to make sure it doesn't accept an empty string from the model-side. But I can check for empty strings in the command itself.

Answer (score 28):

Use a [`MinLengthValidator`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/validators/#minlengthvalidator):

```
from django.core.validators import MinLengthValidator
...
title = models.CharField(max_length=10, validators=[MinLengthValidator(1)])
```