# Followup : missing required Charfield in django Modelform is saved as empty string and do not raise an error

Tags: python, mysql, django, validation, django-models

If I try to save incomplete model instance in Django 1.10, I would expect Django to raise an error. It does not seem to be the case.

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Essai(models.Model):
    ch1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    ch2 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
```

So I have two fields not allowed to be empty (default behavior, `NOT NULL` restriction is applied by Django at MySQL table creation). I expect Django to rase an error if one of the fields is not set before storing.

However, when I create an incomplete instance, the data is stored just fine:

```
>>> from test.models import Essai
>>> bouh = Essai()
>>> bouh.ch1 = "some content for ch1"
>>> bouh.save()
>>> bouh.id
9
>>> bouh.ch1
'some content for ch1'
>>> bouh.ch2
''
>>>
```

I would have expected Django to raise an error. If I force `ch2` to `None`, however, it raises an error:

```
>>> bouh = Essai()
>>> bouh.ch1 = "some content for ch1"
>>> bouh.ch2 = None
>>> bouh.save()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  (...)
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: test_essai.ch2
>>> bouh.id
>>> bouh.ch1
'some content for ch1'
>>> bouh.ch2
>>>
```

Explanation: Django is not raising an error as default behavior in this simple case because in SQL empty string `""` is not equivalent to NULL, as stated in [Django model blank=False does not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17816229/django-model-blank-false-does-not-work)

Now, if we look at ModelForm behavior, there seem to be a inconsistency in django doc:

According to:
 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/#selecting-the-fields-to-use

> Django will prevent any attempt to save an incomplete model, so if the model does not allow the missing fields to be empty, and does not provide a default value for the missing fields, any attempt to save() a ModelForm with missing fields will fail. To avoid this failure, you must instantiate your model with initial values for the missing, but required fields:(…)

a modelForm should not be saved with a missing field if there is no default value.

So with this ModelForm:

`class EssaiModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Essai
        fields = ['ch1']`

A form with only one field `ch1` is generated.

- If `ch1` is left empty, the validation fails at `EssaiModelFormInstance.is_valid()` as expected.
- If `ch1` contains a value, the validation succeeds even though `ch2` is still missing. Then the EssaiModelFormInstance.save() succeeds, contrary to what is claimed in django documentation. `ch2` is empty string and thus is compatible with SQL requirements (`NOT NULL`).

So it seems that there is a default default value empty string `""` for Charfield that is **not accepted** in form validation but that is **accepted** in save() validation. This may require clarification in the documentation.

Comment: original post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39714214/missing-required-charfield-in-django-is-saved-as-empty-string-and-do-not-raise-a

Comment: I agree it should be documented.  After several minutes of searching, I can't find any reference to it.  I would expect not passing a required value to a model constructor to cause Django to complain, not to quietly shove empty string in there.

Answer (score 0):

As the two fields `ch1` and `ch2` are always required in your case, all you need to do is modify your model such that

```
from django.db import models

class Essai(models.Model):
    ch1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ch2 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

and include the fields in the form as

```
class EssaiModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Essai
    fields = ['ch1', 'ch2']
```

Django will automatically raise a validation error for this fields on `is_valid()`

Or if you want to disallow empty string inputs to these fields `blank=False` will not work

Refer this [Django - how to set blank = False, required = False](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6194988/django-how-to-set-blank-false-required-false)

Answer (score 0):

There is a slightly notable difference in model and it's forms. Model.save() performs no validation. So if it fails then probably it raises a database level IntegrityError. For reducing risks of failure at database layer one need to call Model.full_clean() which is also done by ModelForm as documented here in [django's validating objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects).

In my opinion, I expect from django that ModelForms are meant to validate and save data entered by client. Model instantiated programmatically should follow the same control before saving into database.